# Testing Library - Test onChange not called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I encountered the following - I need to write a test that checks if `onChange` is not executed if the same value is clicked.

Here is the onChange:

```
const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
if (sameValueClicked) return; 

setValue(event.target.value)
};
```

And here is the test I have thus far:

```
it('Does not call onChange if same value selected', async () => {
  render(
    <ValuePicker
      value={"1st"}
      onChange={jest.fn()}
    />
  );

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('Value Picker'));
  await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole('dialog'));

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('1st'));
  expect(screen.queryByRole('dialog')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Right now, the test passes if the dialog that is opening stays open but that is not the optimal solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Show some more context: what is `sameValueClicked`, `setValue()` ?

Comment: A clear problem statement is needed. *the dialog that is opening stays open* - what's the meaning of this? *that is not the optimal solution* - what would optimal solution look like and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: @k-wasilewski: `sameValueClicked` is a boolean field that indicates if the same value, as the current one was clicked. `setValue` is a function that sets the current value.

@EstusFlask: Upon choosing a value, the dialog that displays the values should close. I imagine the optional solution something in the lines of: `if the same value is clicked, make sure onChange is not executed`.

Comment: I meant: show us the `setValue()` implementation. Anyway, you can test if a function is being called, as @Muhammad Ali sugested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your click events in `act` and then test the functionality.

```
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

// ...

it('Does not call onChange if same value selected', async () => {
  const onChange = jest.fn()
  render(
    <ValuePicker
      value={"1st"}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );

  act(() => fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('Value Picker')));
  act(() => fireEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('1st')));
  expect(onChange).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I wish to remove the `expect(screen.queryByRole('dialog')).toBeInTheDocument()` and judge the test on something else.

Comment: Yes, you can test if value has changed or not and if the function is being called or not. Let me edit the answer a bit.

Comment: Edited the answer for not calling the function behavior, you can test if the function is being called, i.e. `toHaveBeenCalled` and more appropriate one would be `toHaveBeenCalledWith` and test the passed arguments as well.

Comment: This is not the case, fireEvent already calls act internally.

Comment: I see, then you can just wait for changes just like before. Is expect working as expected?

Comment: I can confirm it did work :) Even without the `act()`. Thank you!